# Why is my Firebase Firestore query not in order_by?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've read several other questions but they all seem to be where the date is stored as a string, not as a time stamp.  Here is my field:

[image]

I am trying to return the the documents in order of my upload_timestamp field but they appear to be in random order... this is my Python Flask code:

```
@app.route('/uploads/<string:last_doc>', methods=['GET'])

def uploads(last_doc=False):

    rentalAgreements = db.collection('rentals')
    query = rentalAgreements.where('username', '==', 'johnny5isalive').order_by('upload_timestamp', direction=firestore.Query.ASCENDING).limit(5)
    results = query.get()

    response = {}
    for doc in results:
        response[doc.id] = doc.to_dict()
        last_doc = doc.id
        print(doc.id)
    response['last_doc'] = last_doc

    return jsonify({"response" : response})
```

The result is this:

```
{
  "response": {
    "4cbacd525c9842bbae29f2f9ef15109f": {
      "filename": "RL 20 DECEMBER 2019v2.csv", 
      "rental_list": "4cbacd525c9842bbae29f2f9ef15109f", 
      "status": "imported", 
      "upload_timestamp": "Wed, 01 Jan 2020 19:53:42 GMT", 
      "username": "johnny5isalive"
    }, 
    "82e8f254607a49699d7986bf7cd7cbae": {
      "filename": "RL 20 DECEMBER 2019v2.csv", 
      "rental_list": "82e8f254607a49699d7986bf7cd7cbae", 
      "status": "imported", 
      "upload_timestamp": "Sat, 28 Dec 2019 08:44:08 GMT", 
      "username": "johnny5isalive"
    }, 
    "874d39a8cfb246bbbc5a722498dff651": {
      "filename": "RL 20 DECEMBER 2019.csv", 
      "rental_list": "874d39a8cfb246bbbc5a722498dff651", 
      "status": "imported", 
      "upload_timestamp": "Fri, 27 Dec 2019 19:52:52 GMT", 
      "username": "johnny5isalive"
    }, 
    "adf6b21511774656a5ed0391618e5ad9": {
      "filename": "RL 20 DECEMBER 2019.csv", 
      "rental_list": "adf6b21511774656a5ed0391618e5ad9", 
      "status": "imported", 
      "upload_timestamp": "Wed, 01 Jan 2020 19:53:36 GMT", 
      "username": "johnny5isalive"
    }, 
    "c738e86053704fd6b3ce70395696b950": {
      "filename": "RL 20 DECEMBER 2019vparent-child.csv", 
      "rental_list": "c738e86053704fd6b3ce70395696b950", 
      "status": "imported", 
      "upload_timestamp": "Wed, 01 Jan 2020 16:57:35 GMT", 
      "username": "johnny5isalive"
    },
    "last_doc": "4cbacd525c9842bbae29f2f9ef15109f"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because us are using dict (`response = {}`) which does not meant to be ordered. So you are getting the values from Firestore in the order, but after inserting to dict the order is lost.

You can use OrderedDict. I found good reference and example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ordereddict-in-python/)

I hope it will help:)

Comment: Thanks Witold - makes total sense.. comes out ordered.. when I jsonify it though it's unordered again :-) turns out the JSON standard doesn't have to maintain order so I'm just going to sort in the front end!